# Conservative field in $~\mathbb R ^2$ \ $\{(0,0)\}~?$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Sorry if I make some mistakes with terminology but I'm studying that in Italian, any way...

I have a lot of exam question very similar each other. One of example:

$$\Omega = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left \{(0,0)  \right \}$$
$$F:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$$
$$F(x,y) = (\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2}})$$
$$\gamma :[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $$
$$\gamma(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$$

They gave me some answers to choose and the correct answer is: $$\int_{\gamma} F dl  = 0$$ because the field is conservative.

My question is: why is conservative if the field has a hole and so it's not a simply connected space?

(I know the integral result is 0... it's a theory question)

Comment: You're confusing what the theorem says. The theorem says that if your domain is simply connected and the vector field has vanishing curl then the vector field is the gradient of some function (hence the integral over any closed loop vanishes). From this alone you cannot conclude anything about what happens if your domain is not simply connected. As the answer below shows, there is an explicit potential function even though your domain is not simply connected; this is no contradiction at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it's written like that, I presume the expectation was that you should have recognized immediately $F$ as being the gradient of a function $G:\Bbb R^2\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R$. I suggest $G(x,y)=\frac23\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/4}$.